# Integration by parts stochastic processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, integration-by-parts

I know the following ($S_t$ = stock, $B_t$ = bond price)
$$
d(X_tY_t) = dX_tY_t + X_tdY_t + dY_tdX_t 
$$
And i have the following multiplication table:
$$
\begin{array}
\hline
\times & dW_t & dt\\
dW_t & dt & 0 \\
dt & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
$$

Now i was solving the following: $dB_t^* =d\left(\frac{B_t}{S_t}\right)$
$$
dB_t^* =d\left(\frac{B_t}{S_t}\right) = B_tdS^{-1}_t + B_t dS_t^{-1} +dS_t^{-1}dB_t
$$
was my first try. However the answer sheet suggested that the final term cancels out. Could someone point me in the right direction as to why this is the case? I would think that it would not be the case in general. This is of course homework, but i am missing the explanation as to why my gut feeling is incorrect.

For reference:
$$
\begin{align}
 S_t &= S_0 \exp([\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2]t + \sigma W_t)\\
B_t &= e^{rt}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I think you have the same term twice in your $dB^*_t=\ldots$ equation

Answer (score 0):

Use Ito's lemma. First,
\begin{align}
d(S_t^{-1}) &= \left[\mu S_t(-S_t^{-2}) + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2S_t^2(2S_t^{-3})
 \right]dt + \sigma S_t (-S_t^{-2})dW_t \\
&= \left[ -\mu S_t^{-1} +\sigma^2S_t^{-1} \right]dt - \frac{\sigma}{S_t}dW_t
\end{align}
Then:
\begin{align*}
d(S_t^{-1})dB_t 
&= \left( 
\left[ -\mu S_t^{-1} +\sigma^2S_t^{-1} \right] dt -
\frac{\sigma}{S_t} dW_t 
\right) re^{rt} dt \\
&= \left( 
\left[ -\mu S_t^{-1} +\sigma^2S_t^{-1} \right] \underbrace{(dt)^2}_0 -
\frac{\sigma}{S_t} \underbrace{dW_tdt }_0
\right)re^{rt}\\
&=0
\end{align*}

---

Alternatively, use Ito's lemma on the full $dB^*_t=d(S_t^{-1}B_t)$.
\begin{align}
dB^*_t
&= d\left(\frac{B_t}{S_t}\right) \\
&= \left[ 
re^{rt}S_t^{-1} + \mu S_t e^{rt} (-1)S_t^{-2} + \frac{\sigma^2S_t^2}{2} 2 B_t S_t^{-1}
\right]dt + \sigma S_t(-B_tS_t^{-2})dW_t \\
&= re^{rt}dtS_t^{-1} + e^{rt}\left( S_t^{-1}[\sigma^2 - \mu]dt - \frac{\sigma }{S_t}dW_t \right) \\
&= dB_t S_t^{-1} +B_t d(S_t
\end{align}

---

Note that $S_t$ satisfies:
$$
dS_t = \mu S_tdt + \sigma S_t dW_t 
= \tilde{\mu}(S_t)dt + \tilde{\sigma}(S_t)dW_t
$$